Given an isosceles triangle and that the circumcenter is inside of it, how do I find the ratio of areas of the smaller triangles to the big one?

Given the isosceles triangle $_\Delta ABC$ ($AB=BC$) and its circumcenter $O$, I'd like to know the following ratios of areas:

$_\Delta AOB$ to $_\Delta ABC$;
$_\Delta COB$ to $_\Delta ABC$;
$_\Delta AOC$ to $_\Delta ABC$.

My observations:

By SSS, $_\Delta AOB \equiv _\Delta COB$. Therefore, their areas are also equal.
As circumcenter of isosceles triangle lies on the same line with the altitude to the base, the area of $_\Delta AOC$ to $_\Delta ABC$ is the same as the ratio of $BO$ to $BH$ where $BH$ perpendicular to $AC$.

How to I find out these ratios?

If you write $\angle AOB=2\theta$ (or $\angle ACB=\theta$), then $\Delta AOB:\Delta AOC$ would be equal to $\sin2\theta:-\sin4\theta=1:-2\cos2\theta$.

Let $[XYZ]$ denote the area of the shape bound by points $X, Y, Z$.
Observe that $OA = OB = OC$ so we can use the $A = \frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$ formula for area of a triangle to get
$$[AOB]:[BOC]:[COA] = \sin \angle AOB : \sin \angle BOC = \sin \angle COA$$
Letting $\alpha = \angle AOB$, we get
$$[AOB]:[BOC]:[COA] = \sin\alpha : \sin 2\alpha : \sin\alpha = 1 : 2\cos\alpha : 1$$
Hence using $[ABC] = [AOB] + [BOC] + [COA]$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{[AOB]}{[ABC]} &= \frac{1}{2(1 + \cos\alpha)}\\
\frac{[BOC]}{[ABC]} &= \frac{1}{2(1 + \cos\alpha)}\\
\frac{[COA]}{[ABC]} &= \frac{\cos\alpha}{1 + \cos\alpha}
\end{align*}
You can use $\alpha = 2\angle ACB$ if you'd like an expression in terms of the angles of the triangle.

Using barycentric coordinates(see examples of special points) and Conway triangle notations, it is well known that
$$_\Delta AOB:_\Delta BOC:_\Delta COA=a^2S_A:b^2S_B:c^2S_C$$ for any triangle.
Here, $c=a$. So $$S_A=\frac12b^2;\,S_B=\frac12(2a^2-b^2);\,S_C=\frac12b^2$$So, $$_\Delta AOB:_\Delta BOC:_\Delta COA=a^2:2a^2-b^2:a^2$$In particular, you find your first observation.
So, $$\frac{_\Delta AOB}{_\Delta ABC}=\frac{a^2}{4a^2-b^2}\label{a}.\tag1$$and so on.
In particular, if $a=b, $ you have each ratio equal to $\frac13$ of course.

In the animation provided, you can move $C$ to see $\eqref{a}$ in algebraic window. When $C=F$, the ratio is equal to $\frac13$ as already said.
https://www.geogebra.org/classic/tkjyutsz
